# Prettier shell script format

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, visual-studio-code, prettier

Can I format template literal embedded shell script with Prettier ?

Example:

Before formating:

```js
import {bash} from 'random-bash-runner'

await bash`
a_bash_command argument1 \
     main-dev \
argument4 --database=name --quiet`
```

After formatting:

```js
import {bash} from 'random-bash-runner'

await bash`
  a_bash_command argument1 \
    main-dev \
    argument4 l \
    --database=name --quiet
`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prettier can, with the setting `--embedded-language-formatting=auto` (see [here](https://prettier.io/blog/2020/08/24/2.1.0.html)), format templates.

However, the languages it can format (from it's extension page on VSCode) are:

```
JavaScript · TypeScript · Flow · JSX · JSON
CSS · SCSS · Less
HTML · Vue · Angular
GraphQL · Markdown · YAML
```

So I'm afraid no, this cannot be accomplished by Prettier as `bash` or `shell` are not on this list.

Comment: Shell script is being formatted if it is inside a template literal embedded markdown script. Wondering if markdown prettier plugin could be modified to accomplish this transformation ? 

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/un-ts/prettier/tree/master/packages/sh

Answer (score 4):

Most languages have their own `fmt` command.

Prettier is for web languages that are run by committees and don't have the same kind of leadership pushing forward practical developer tools.

For shell languages use `shfmt` and `shellcheck`:

- shfmt source: https://github.com/mvdan/sh
- shfmt cheatsheet: https://webinstall.dev/shfmt/
- vim-shfmt cheatsheet: https://webinstall.dev/vim-shfmt/
- shellcheck source: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck
- shellcheck cheatsheet: https://webinstall.dev/shellcheck/
- vim-shellcheck cheatsheet: https://webinstall.dev/shellcheck/

These follow Google's shell style and linting guidelines. Not that Google is perfect, but this is good stuff - it taught me proper shell scripting 10x better in just one year of using them than after 15+ years of doing it here and there without them.

Answer (score 1):

Prettier cannot format bash files. Instead you can try either [shell-format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=foxundermoon.shell-format) or [Bash Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shakram02.bash-beautify) extensions for VSCode to format your bash scripts.

Comment: I already use vs-shell-format for my bash scripts. Google recently released [zx](https://github.com/google/zx) which is a helper to run shell script in javascript. You can already format a few embedded language with Prettier (see answer above from @RolvApneseth) but shell script is not one of them . Thanks